# How to control UIButton on View without IB

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I put some UIButtons on UIScrollView without IB.

If I click one button, other buttons are turned off except selected button.
But, When I click another button, other button ( except selected button) are turned off.

I can't confirm count of UIButtons on UIScrollView.
Because count of UIButtons are changed dynamically.

Without IB, How can I control UIButton on UIScrollView?

Plese tell me your advice. Thanks!

Comment: You can maintain a NSMutableArray with buttons inside your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
for(id button in [scrollView subViews])
{
    if([button isKindOfClass[UIButton class]])
    {
        count++;
    }
}

NSLog("total buttons: %d",count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag the UIButtons when creating them `[myButton setTag:MY_BUTTON_1]` and later use this information when the button is tapped

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if ([button tag] == MY_BUTTON_1) { /* do something with this button */ }
    else if ([button tag] == MY_BUTTON_2) { /* do something differently */ }
    else return;
}
```